# python convert strings into sets of characters

Tags: python

```
c=['a,b,c','a,b,c','a,b']
for item in c:
    a=set(item.replace("'",""))
    b=list(a)
print b
```

It returns:

```
['a','b',',']
```

What I want is :

```
['a','b','c']
```

How do I convert these strings into sets of characters?

Comment: Why are you replacing the `'`? It doesn't exist in the strings.

Comment: Also, your `b` gets overwritten for each iteration. Where are you getting `c` from?

Comment: @JohnSmith: I don't think you're understanding. `'` isn't in the list. The object enclosed in `''` is a string. the `'` just tells you that that is what it is. The question I think you're trying to ask is "how do I a) convert these strings into sets of characters and b) find the intersection over all these sets."

Comment: If you want unique members of that list, wouldn't that be `['a,b,c', 'a,b']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c = ['a,b,c', 'a,b,c', 'a,b']
print (set (''.join (c).replace (',', '') ) )
```

Comment: But OP asked about "How do I convert these strings into sets of characters?", and not sets of strings of characters. I don't know though.

Comment: Sure. I'd probably do it this way to save on string replacement operations: `set(','.join (c).split(','))`

Answer (score 6):

```
c = ['a,b,c','a,b,c','a,b']
result = set()
for item in c:
  result.update(item.split(','))
print result
```

Here's what I did:

1. Create a set called `result` so that we can store the values in it
2. Iterate through the strings in `c` and for each string, we split it into a new list of strings when we see a ',' character.
3. Update the `result` set with the values from splitting the string
4. Print the result

Because `result` is a set, it cannot contain multiple instances of the same item. So when we call `result.update()` any duplicate entries are automatically ignored.

If you want the results sorted like your desired output, you have to do the following since sets are unordered:

```
result = list(result)
result.sort()
print result
```

Lists have a built in sort method. So creating a list from the set and then calling `sort()` on it will sort the list in place, meaning that it does not return anything but modifies the list itself. Doing this will give you `['a', 'b', 'c']` which is what you wanted in your question.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> c=['a,b,c','a,b,c','a,b']
>>> print set(unique for charlist in c for unique in charlist.split(','))
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```